# Group_by row and collaspe value from one variable keeping the other variables

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I have this following dataframe

```
data=data.frame(id=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d"),
                  val1=c(0,0,0,89,89,5,5,5,5,4),
                  val2=c(6,6,6,9,9,8,8,8,8,9),
                  Clin3=c(11,11,11,5,5,3,3,3,3,3),
                  Clin4=c(9,9,9,78,78,0,0,0,0,1),
                  res=c("Pal:7", "Pal:8", "Pml:7", "Poi:2", "Oiu:5", "Rtf:4", "Pml:8", "Oiu:9", "Edr:5", "Pal:8"))

> data
   id val1 val2 clin3 clin4   res
1   a    0    6   11    9 Pal:7
2   a    0    6   11    9 Pal:8
3   a    0    6   11    9 Pml:7
4   b   89    9    5   78 Poi:2
5   b   89    9    5   78 Oiu:5
6   c    5    8    3    0 Rtf:4
7   c    5    8    3    0 Pml:8
8   c    5    8    3    0 Oiu:9
9   c    5    8    3    0 Edr:5
10  d    4    9    3    1 Pal:8
```

I would like to group my dataframe by id and collaspe the value of res, keeping the other variable. I saw example with summarise but it doesn't do what I want as it summarise accross all the variable. Please see below the expected output.

```
data %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(across(res, ~ paste(unique(.x[!is.na(.x)]), collapse = ", ")))
```

```
> output
  id val1 val2 clin3 clin4                     res
1  a    0    6   11    9       Pal:7_Pal:8_Pml:7
2  b   89    9    5   78             Poi:2_Oiu:5
3  c    5    8    3    0 Rtf:4_Pml:8_Oiu:9_Edr:5
4  d    4    9    3    1                   Pal:8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar, though slightly less complex option would be:

```r
data %>% summarise(res = paste(res, collapse = '_'), .by = -res)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Groups:   id, val1, val2, Clin3 [4]
#>   id     val1  val2 Clin3 Clin4 res                    
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                  
#> 1 a         0     6    11     9 Pal:7_Pal:8_Pml:7      
#> 2 b        89     9     5    78 Poi:2_Oiu:5            
#> 3 c         5     8     3     0 Rtf:4_Pml:8_Oiu:9_Edr:5
#> 4 d         4     9     3     1 Pal:8
```